# Installation mod_wsgi for python3.2

Tags: apache, debian, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-3.2

I`m trying to install mod_wsgi for Python 3.2 on Debian 6 (Squeeze).

First I installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 from default repository, and it was for Python3.1, then I add to source.list

```
*deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main*
```

and call *apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3* again. After that sys.version in wsgi returs 3.2.3.

Is it truly mod-wsgi works with Python3.2 or that just bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If wishing to use Python 3.2, you must compile mod_wsgi from source code out of the mod_wsgi source code repository. Last tar ball and binary packages from distros wouldn't support 3.2.

Comment: I tried to compile mod_wsgi for python 3.2 several times, but always something got wrong. In the best case, Apache throw`s error on start

Comment: Using version obtained from what URL and what actual error? Recommended you take issue to mod_wsgi mailing list as SO is bad place for debugging issues that don't have obvious answers.